# Why this javascript is not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am using the following javascript to dynamically add rows in a table:-

```
    var trObj = document.createElement('tr');
    trObj.setAttribute('name', 'dynamicTR');

    var tdObjEmpty = document.createElement('td');
    tdObjEmpty.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
    tdObjEmpty.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'
    trObj.appendChild ( tdObjEmpty );

    var tdObj = document.createElement('td');
    tdObj.setAttribute('colspan', '15');
    tdObj.innerHTML = postingDivObj.innerHTML; // <-- copy the innerHTML
    trObj.appendChild ( tdObj );    
    parentObj = approvedDisapprovedTableObj.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];               
    targetElementObj = getNthTr ( parentObj, rowIndex1 - extraTr ); // <-- it will just return the trObject, 
    if ( targetElementObj ){
        parentObj.insertBefore(trObj, targetElementObj.nextSibling )
    }else{
        //alert ( 'targetElementObj is null' );
    }
```

This is working in FF as well as in IE, [ but, i guess, in case of IE **name** and **colspan** attribute is not set using setAttribute. but not sure ] .

Now, when i have to remove all rows which are dynamically created i use:-

```
dynamicTRObjs = document.getElementsByName('dynamicTR');
    if ( dynamicTRObjs ){
            parentObj = approvedDisapprovedTableObj.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            for ( i = 0 ; i < dynamicTRObjs.length; i++ ){              
                parentObj.removeChild ( dynamicTRObjs[i] );          
                extraTr++;
            } 
        }
```

This code removes all dynamically created TRs. and it works fine in FF, but not in IE.
Also in case of IE `dynamicTRObjs.length` is always 0,whereas in FF `dynamicTRObjs.length` it gives correct number of rows. Please tell me what i am missing here.

Comment: is there a reason you don't use e. g. jquery?  not only would your code be like 80% shorter, it would most probably work cross-browser.

Comment: there is no specific reason for tht.

Comment: The question was 'how do I do it in JS', not 'how do I do it in jQuery'.

Comment: @Michiel Kalkman: jquery is a JS library, not a different language.  avoiding tools that help one get the job done quickly and reliably is IMO poor engineering.

Comment: What you are missing is that the spec for getElementsByName is that it only returns "form controls" of that name in xhtml. I would definitely set a class on the dom node and look for elements with that className.

Should definitely use jquery, ext, prototype or something. Writing your own code to search for nodes is reinventing the wheel every time. If you don't like libs, at least roll out your own method to perform dom queries. ff already has a getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 9):

The HTML4 spec [list of attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html) lists elements that the *name* attribute can be set on.  Tables and table elements are not on the list. The most obvious option is one of,

- Keep references to all TRs you create so you don't have to find them in the DOM
- Set a className on your TRs and use selectors to find them

That Firefox uses getElementsByName 'correctly' and IE does not is something others have run into too. I'd just avoid using *name* here altogether.

Comment: +1 `Set a className on your TRs and use selectors to find them` i am going to use it now, i think it should work.

Comment: var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamicTR'); #=> Array of TRs
That should do it.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will not work in IE :(  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c%5Fcore.html

Comment: @Rakesh Juyal : doh! I forgot that. If you don't mind polluting global scope you can push all the dynamic TRs to an array there. Not very clean, I admit, but it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

getElementsByName() is not working well in IE6-8

I would suggest that you some other way of identifying that element if you want cross browser usability.

Comment: oh great, now what should i do? Please suggest something Mike

Comment: you could give them a common id

Comment: `you could give them a common id` let me try this too

Comment: ID attributes have to be unique per document instance. The function is document.getElementById() - singular.

Comment: I always just keep an array of my dynamic objects in memory, because finding them later is expansive. Avoid working with the DOM when you can.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's a bit off-topic, but let me give you a small advice on using getElementsByName functionality in a browser. It will not help you to solve the current problem (which is because TR can not have Name attribute ), but it will definitely help you to prevent future problems which you will met.

getElementsByName returns you collection, which always keeps itself up-to-date with the DOM tree. This means, that at the moment when you remove ONE item with removeChild, the SIZE of collection will be decreased. So, if you will removing nodes and keep relying on the length of the collection, not all nodes will be removed.

Check this example of your for loop:

- Collection length is 3, Your i var is 0, i < length
  You remove child,
- collection length is 2, your i var is 1, i < length
  you remove child,
- collection length is 1 and your i var i 2.
  Condition i< length == true that means that for loop will stop, BUT some of the elements will still be presented in the DOM.

Choose any solution you like to fix this, but try to avoid relying on the length of the Collection which is returned by getElementsByTagName.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

since I'm not the only one to suggest avoidance of low-level DOM manipulation, here's an example: an untested implementation with jquery.  not exactly an answer to your question, but a comment would lose the formatting.

```
var mkTd = function (colspan, html)
{
    return $('<td />')
        .attr('colspan', colspan)
        .html(html)
    ;
}

var addRow = function (rowNr)
{
    var target = $('#approvedDisapprovedTableObj tbody tr:eq('+rowNr+')');
    if (!target.length) {
        //alert ( 'target is null' );
        return;
    }
    target.after(
        $('<tr />')
            .addClass('dynamicTR')
            .append(mkTd(2, '&nbsp;')
            .append(mkTd(15, $('#postingDivObj').html()))
    );
}
var dropRows = function ()
{
    $('.dynamicTR').remove();
}
```

notice that the expression `$('.dynamicTR').remove()` achieves the same as your

```
dynamicTRObjs = document.getElementsByName('dynamicTR');
if ( dynamicTRObjs ){
    parentObj = approvedDisapprovedTableObj.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    for ( i = 0 ; i < dynamicTRObjs.length; i++ ){                          
        parentObj.removeChild ( dynamicTRObjs[i] );                      
        extraTr++;
    } 
}
```

IMO it's obvious that the benefits are huge.

Comment: +1 for writing the code using a framework, though we'll just have to agree to disagree on the universal application of frameworks.